# Workflow issues with submitting SharePoint Email

Tags: list, workflow, infopath, email

I am a novice sharepoint user and I have worked on a team that has created a sharepoint list that we are using to process requests.  We have a built-in workflow that is designed to send users an email when the infopath form that is connected to the sharepoint list is submitted.  However, the email that was built into the workflow is not longer being submitted to users. It worked fine when we were testing it, but something has changed.  The security for this form is relatively open so someone could have change the settings, but I am not aware of how to see if there were changes made. Does anyone have any idea why a workflow would not execute properly?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to check the security settings for the form?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to check whether the email is actually being sent. Go to your Exchange server and enable queue logging to track mail passing through the system. Next, fill out the form to send to a known account you have access to and click submit. Go back to the Exchange server and check the queue log. If your email arrives in the next minute or two (depending on your farm topology) then congratulations your form are workflow are fine and you have a mail server problem.

If it turns out that your workflow is to blame then your first point of call should be 
Infopath Designer to check the submit button which should have some embedded logic to cause the workflow to run. If this is correct then open Sharepoint Designer and check that the workflow itself is set up correctly.

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you are referencing regarding the submit button.  Let me clarify myself.  The data is correctly be sent to a sharepoint list.  However, when the submit button is pressed this also triggers a workflow to send a generic email to the user that submitted the request.  The generic email is the action that is not occurring.  Thanks for all of your helpful feedback thus far.

Comment: What version of SahrePoint are you running?

Comment: I believe it is SP 2010

Comment: JonT, we just realized that some users are receiving the email receipt that is triggered upon submission, while others are not.  So we are beginning to suspect that this could be a security issue?  Do you think I am correct in my assertion?  What are your thoughts?

Comment: Very possibly. At the very least you do now know that your workflow and form work correctly.

If I were you, my next move would be to start building a list of who can and can't receive the emails and check it against the membership of user groups of your sharepoint site collections.

Answer (score 0):

Find the library where the form is saved at, click on the "DOWN" arrow next to its name to open the drop-down menu and then click Send To -> Download a Copy. Now you will have a copy of your form on your computer. Open it in Infopath Designer to edit it. In the right-hand side you will have access to all the fields. See what email address the "Submit" button has listed.

Comment: Hi RockonRockOut:  I am not quite sure I am following, the submit button is not linked to an email address at all.  The email is triggered by pressing the submit button.  But the email address is located in workflow designed within the workflow.

Comment: Do you know what kind of workflow it is? They all have different settings. You can see that by going to 
List Settings/Library Settings and then clicking the "Workflow Settings" link.

Comment: Please see my response to JonT above, thanks for all of your help.